# To maintain responsiveness for background image along with drag and drop elements intact and being responsive wrt background image

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a working stack blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-component-example-1rvd1p

I have written custom drag and drop events in Angular and dropping elements on a div containing background image. My objective is to make the div element responsive keeping the positions intact of new dropped elements intact to background image thus also being responsive proportionally to the background image

I tried giving positioning to the parent as well as child container, so the parent div becomes responsive but the child elements(dropped elements) does not remain intact with the parent background image and neither proportional.

In other words when the image will be zoomed out or zoomed in the child elements (dropped elements) should also inc and dec proportionally in size keeping their positions wrt image intact.

Here is the drag and drop working reference 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/draggable-part-6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

```
 <div class="dropzone" appDropzone appMovableArea (drop)="move(currentBox, 
   dropzone1)"  [ngStyle]="{'width':'100%','background-image': 
   'url('+url+')', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-position': 
   'center', 'background-size': '100% 100%'}">
                <div *ngFor="let box of dropzone1" class="box"
                    appDroppable (dragStart)="currentBox = box" appMovable>
                    {{ box.dis }}
                <!--<div class="box" *appDraggableHelper>{{ box }}</div>-->
                </div>
   </div>


 _____________________________________________________________
 |     _______                            background image    |
 |    |       |                                               |
 |    |       | => dropped elements                           |
 |    |_______|              _______                          |
 |                          |       |                         |
 |                          |       |                         |
 |                          |_______|                         |
 |____________________________________________________________|
```

css

```
.dropzone {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: lightgray;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  &.dropzone-activated {
  border: 1px solid red;
  } 

  &.dropzone-entered {
     background-color: #efefef;
    }
  }
```

directives

droppable.directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { DroppableService } from '../_services/droppable.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDroppable]'
})
export class DroppableDirective {

  constructor(private droppableService: DroppableService) { }

  @HostListener('dragStart', ['$event'])
  onDragStart(event: PointerEvent): void {
  this.droppableService.onDragStart(event);
 }

  @HostListener('dragMove', ['$event'])
  onDragMove(event: PointerEvent): void {
  this.droppableService.onDragMove(event);
  }

  @HostListener('dragEnd', ['$event'])
  onDragEnd(event: PointerEvent): void {
    this.droppableService.onDragEnd(event);
 }

}
```

dropzone.directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener, 
OnInit, Output, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { DroppableService } from '../_services/droppable.service';

@Directive({
 selector: '[appDropzone]',
 providers: [DroppableService]
})
export class DropzoneDirective implements OnInit {
@HostBinding('class.dropzone-activated') activated = false;
@HostBinding('class.dropzone-entered') entered = false;

@Output() drop = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();
@Output() remove = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();

private clientRect: ClientRect;

constructor(@SkipSelf() private allDroppableService: DroppableService,
          private innerDroppableService: DroppableService,
          private element: ElementRef) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.allDroppableService.dragStart$.subscribe(() => this.onDragStart());
this.allDroppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe(event => 
this.onDragEnd(event));

this.allDroppableService.dragMove$.subscribe(event => {
  if (this.isEventInside(event)) {
    this.onPointerEnter();
  } else {
    this.onPointerLeave();
  }
 });

  this.innerDroppableService.dragStart$.subscribe(() => 
  this.onInnerDragStart());
  this.innerDroppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe(event => 
  this.onInnerDragEnd(event));
  }

 private onPointerEnter(): void {
  if (!this.activated) {
  return;
 }

this.entered = true;
}

private onPointerLeave(): void {
  if (!this.activated) {
    return;
   }

   this.entered = false;
  }

   private onDragStart(): void {
   this.clientRect = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

   this.activated = true;
  }

   private onDragEnd(event: PointerEvent): void {
   if (!this.activated) {
   return;
  }

    if (this.entered) {
    this.drop.emit(event);
  }

    this.activated = false;
    this.entered = false;
  }

  private onInnerDragStart() {
   this.activated = true;
   this.entered = true;
  }

  private onInnerDragEnd(event: PointerEvent) {
   if (!this.entered) {
   this.remove.emit(event);
 }

    this.activated = false;
    this.entered = false;
  }

  private isEventInside(event: PointerEvent) {
    return event.clientX >= this.clientRect.left &&
      event.clientX <= this.clientRect.right &&
      event.clientY >= this.clientRect.top &&
      event.clientY <= this.clientRect.bottom;
  }
}
```

movable-area.directive

```
import { AfterContentInit, ContentChildren, Directive, ElementRef, QueryList 
} from '@angular/core';
import { MovableDirective } from './movable.directive';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

interface Boundaries {
 minX: number;
 maxX: number;
 minY: number;
 maxY: number;
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMovableArea]'
})
export class MovableAreaDirective implements AfterContentInit {
@ContentChildren(MovableDirective) movables: QueryList<MovableDirective>;

private boundaries: Boundaries;
private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

ngAfterContentInit(): void {
this.movables.changes.subscribe(() => {
  this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());

  this.movables.forEach(movable => {
    this.subscriptions.push(movable.dragStart.subscribe(() => 
  this.measureBoundaries(movable)));
    this.subscriptions.push(movable.dragMove.subscribe(() => 
  this.maintainBoundaries(movable)));
  });
  });

  this.movables.notifyOnChanges();
  }

  private measureBoundaries(movable: MovableDirective) {
  const viewRect: ClientRect = 
  this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const movableClientRect: ClientRect = 
  movable.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

  this.boundaries = {
   minX: viewRect.left - movableClientRect.left + movable.position.x,
   maxX: viewRect.right - movableClientRect.right + movable.position.x,
   minY: viewRect.top - movableClientRect.top + movable.position.y,
   maxY: viewRect.bottom - movableClientRect.bottom + movable.position.y
  };
 }

 private maintainBoundaries(movable: MovableDirective) {
 movable.position.x = Math.max(this.boundaries.minX, movable.position.x);
 movable.position.x = Math.min(this.boundaries.maxX, movable.position.x);
 movable.position.y = Math.max(this.boundaries.minY, movable.position.y);
 movable.position.y = Math.min(this.boundaries.maxY, movable.position.y);
 }
 }
```

component.ts

```
  dropzone1 = [];

 currentBox?: string;

 move(box: string, toList: string[]): void {

  this.removeBox(box, this.rooms);
  this.removeBox(box, this.dropzone1);

  toList.push(box);
 }

 removeBox(item: string, list) {
  if (list.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
  list.splice(list.indexOf(item), 1);
 }
}
```

If this approach is wrong then please suggest the right way to make it work.

The code for converting the blob to image and for uploading it as blob
      Reference of the data I get

```
 "<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" _ngcontent-c18="" appdropzone=""
 appmovablearea="" class="dropzone image-area"
 id="toget" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="width: 100%; 
 background-image: 
 url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAALoAA 
 AC6CAMAAAAu0KfDAAAAwFBMVEX//XkFi/hkn/9ySZhLa0CgAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); 
 background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; back
 ground-size: 100% 100%;"><!--bindings={ 
 "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
 }--><div _ngcontent-c18="" appdroppable="" appmovable=""
 class="box draggable movable ng-star-inserted" touch-action="none" 
  style="transform: translateX(136.8px) translateY(112.8px);"> vav18 </div> 
 </div>"

   downloadImageFromBlob('abc', (err, data) => {
   if (data) {
    this.url = data.split('url(&quot;')[1].split('&quot;); background- 
    repeat: no-repeat;')[0];
    data = data.replace(/&quot;/g,'')
    this.myHtmlString = data;
    }
    }

  <div id="existing" *ngIf="!abc" class="image-area" 
  [innerHTML]="myHtmlString | safeHtml"></div>


  uploadImage(): void {
  var svgString = new 
  XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById('toget'));

  var svgBlob = new Blob([svgString], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" 
 });

  let file = this.fileUploadService.convertToFile(svgBlob, "floorPlan.svg");
  }
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding the issue here. Are you saying you want the boxes to stay in the exact spot they're dragged to?  Can you point out or replicate this problem in your stackblitz?

Comment: I have given a reference in the starting , https://stackblitz.com/edit/draggable-part-6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts , when I decrease the rendered dropzone the boxes within it doesn't stay at the same position , as mentioned [elements intact and being responsive wrt to background image dec, inc]

Comment: what you're saying still isn't very clear. Can you give an exact set of steps to reproduce with expected outcome and actual outcome?

Comment: So you want to make sort of an image editing tool where you can drag objects into the dropzone containing the image in the background to decorate the image. Show us what have you tried so far so we can help you proceed, the stackblitz link you provided is right out of a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwdoRTqMtM8).

Comment: Yeah I have given the ref , and I am having some roadblocks keeping the child elements on the static pos wrt to background image and second issue when I download the image and embed it into hmtl , the dropzone is not working, it would be great if u could help. Thanks

Comment: i need to see the part of your code where you actually style the dropped elements for their positioning.  that part is completely missing in post and blitz.  It sounds like you're doing it with absolute px values when you want to be computing %

Comment: @bryan60 in movable directive it is being used in px , could you please throw some light , I mean help me out thanks

Comment: but I can't see how you're using it at all. I want to help but I can't help your code without seeing your code.

Comment: @bryan60 In Stackblitz , under draggable folder, movable.directive.ts is there which in turn i sbeing used in movable-area.directive.ts, so movable.directive.ts has px values of x and y

Comment: I had used positioning properties absolute to child divs and tried out , I have mentioned in the begining of my query

Comment: @bryan60 the directives are being used using contentChildren in movable-area

Comment: ok, sorry but I can't help you as you will not show your actual code.

Comment: I have given the HTML code the ts code as well and this is the code that I have in my app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196996/discussion-between-enthu-and-bryan60).

Comment: If you are placing the dragged element with pixel values, you need to convert them into % instead. You can do so by using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the width and height of the parent when the drag event stop, and deducing % with it (`top / height * 100` and `left / width * 100` respectively). Bonus points for executing this in a [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) callback to avoid performances drop

Comment: I know it's not in the question, but this may be a good place to use D3. There is a very competent Angular integration for it and manipulating multiple raster items in precise relation to one another is one of the things it does well. Then again, if you've never used it, the learning curve may be steeper than getting your existing code working.

Comment: @StephanSamuel Can u give me answer to this context if it works i'll accept and u will get bounty as well :)

Comment: @Enthu I'd love to but that represents writing a lot of code. I could give you a basic outline of the solution. Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a slightly different solution: instead of managing the objects as sprites *on top of* the SVG, you could *add them to* the SVG.

A rough procedural outline:

1. Make sure you're using a copy of the SVG base file because you're going to modify it. I think you're already doing this.
2. Use your NG service to add a group (`g` element). Make sure it's positioned above (draws after) the existing SVG elements. This is what you'll want to keep a handle to in your directive.
3. On drag-drop, add an SVG `rect` element, to the new group. You've already got the positioning logic but it'll need to be converted to be aware of SVG scaling and viewporting.
4. Use SVG's eventing to bubble events into NG. This should be able to be wrapped in an NG directive easily since the SVG is really just HTML that lives in your document.
5. At this point you should be able to redirect your move and scale events into SVG scaling and viewporting. That is, when you rescale, you simply rescale the SVG. Your dropped boxes will rescale with the rest of the drawing.

There are a few things that you can probably do that will make this easier for you:

- Try an NG-aware SVG manipulation library. I haven't checked but there's got to be one out there. This could save you writing directive wrappers.
- Look into a mapping solution. Maybe try [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/), using NG wrapper hints from [here](https://codehandbook.org/use-leaflet-in-angular/). Aside from the fact that you're actually drawing a map, managing a base vector image with additional sprites on it is exactly what mapping solutions do. No need to re-invent the wheel. Just redirect the map read from some world map provider to fetch your SVG.
- I had made a comment to try [D3](https://d3js.org/), which many people have used to annotate maps. [This simple example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590) from their gallery does part of your work already. I can't imagine that there isn't a working NG wrapper for D3.

Hopefully something in there will help you along the way.

**Update** (some questions from the comments answered)

**On D3 or other libraries:** Adding another library will affect performance, particularly, it will slow it down. This is always the case when you add more code that runs.

I think the better question is, "if I add another library, will my performance degrade to below an acceptable level?" That depends on the library, some details about it (like where it's loaded from and how you use it) and what your level of acceptable performance is. I am not a believer in writing code to be ultimately performant from the start: write *maintainable* code and optimize particular things to match particular requirements later. That being said, it's silly to link in a library that will definitely and obviously blow performance out of the water using any reasonable standard.

If your project already loads D3, especially if you (personally) aren't too familiar with it, beware that it's possible to write code that takes a perfectly good library and makes it do way more stuff than it has to. This will kill your performance. This case is also most likely for first-time consumers of a library. If there's someone on your project who knows D3, I would recommend enlisting their aid, at least in a code review when you're done.

**On doing this in pure HTML/CSS/JS:** of course this is possible. You've already started implementing one of them.

There is a solution that requires *less* JS, involving CSS clipping and transforms. They act very similar to SVG viewports and transforms, but they come with denser code listings. That is, you'll have to accomplish in one line of CSS what you could have spread out over many SVG elements and attributes. This will be more complicated to debug and maintain. Given your original post, it seems that your biggest problem is debugging. Given the number and quality of answers to your question (as of this edit), it seems that no one on SO really wants to help you debug. If I was in your position, I would focus on maintainability and debug-ability in order to get your project completed.

That being said, the general idea is this:

- Put everything in a single HTML `div`.
- Stack your elements inside that, starting with the SVG, then the green boxes atop. You've already done this. You may need to manipulate `z-order` if you haven't already done so.
- Respond to events (scroll and zoom) by having the JS change the CSS [clip rectangle](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) and [transform scaling](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/), directly on the parent `div`.

Using this, everything inside the parent `div` should pan or scale. Of course, then you're right back to your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the response I'll try out next week and keep you posted, but using external libraries (NG-aware SVG manipulation, Leaflet)would impact app performance, please correct me if I am wrong, I'll try the D3 approach as D3 is already being used in my application, though I have never used D3, but if its possible using D3 I would definitely go with that. And one more thing I wanted to ask is as I have the green color boxes in HTML, CSS, isn't it possible using normal CSS, HTML to maintain the positions of the divs over SVG image(keeping SVG image as background image)

Comment: Considering a parent container containing the background image which is a SVG and in that parent div calculating the position of the child divs(green boxes)  and again when this whole element per se is rendered or zoomed in, zoomed out the positions and size of the child divs to be relative to the parent container